# Maven cannot find git

Tags: c++, configuration

I'm trying to build a `maven` project. It"s a project that can be found in this link :

https://www.openmicroscopy.org/site/support/bio-formats5.0/developers/BF-CPP-windows.html

I have this error :

```
maven - execute failed: java.io.ioexception: cannot run program git
```

I have my `git` installation in this path and i have add that to my enviroment variable.

```
C:/Users/xxxxx/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/cmd/git.exe
```

I dont understand how `maven` cannot find `git`.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not related to maven or git. I had a look on the pom you are trying to use. At some point the expect 'git' to be available in the $PATH!
So make sure you have  git in your $PATH on your system, meaning that by opening a terminal / Command prompt and typing git you get it working.